# How to show latest and high price value first using Views?

Tags: 7, views

I am using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to show products in my site. I need to filter my view with high price and latest product . Using expose filter not a sort criteria.

Comment: is your requirement is to implement sort by price or relevance option for anonymous users..??

Comment: yes for all user..

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your requirement, you have to expose the sort criteria. Select checkbox **Expose this sort to visitors, to allow them to change it** under sort criterion configuration.

Note: When you add any field into SORT CRITERIA, then under this field configuration you can see this option.

Comment: ok let me check. But I need same functionality via filter not sort

Comment: When you add any field into SORT CRITERIA, then under this field configuration you can see this option.